# Prove $A_{\infty} < \infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, martingales, stopping-times

From Williams' Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

How do we know that $A_{\infty} < \infty$?

If $T = \infty$, then

$$E[A_{T \wedge n}] \le (K+c)^2$$

$$\to E[A_{n}] \le (K+c)^2$$

$$\to \lim E[A_{n}] \le (K+c)^2$$

$$\to E[\lim A_{n}] \le (K+c)^2$$

$$\to E[\lim A_{n}] < \infty$$

$$\to \lim A_{n} < \infty$$

$$\to A_{\infty} < \infty$$

If $T < \infty$, then

$$E[A_{T \wedge n}] \le (K+c)^2$$

$$\to \lim E[A_{T \wedge n}] \le (K+c)^2$$

$$\stackrel{Why?}{\to} E[\lim A_{T \wedge n}] \le (K+c)^2$$

$$\to E[A_{T}] \le (K+c)^2$$

I'm stuck. How can I approach this?

Comment: Bear in mind that $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^2$ is non-random.

Comment: @JohnDawkins right but AT is random?

Comment: Yes, $A_T$ is random.

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: @SangchulLee ah thanks but what about the finite case?

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem works regardless of whether $T$ is finite of infinite. We simply have $\Bbb{E}[A_T] = \lim_{n\to\infty} \Bbb{E}[A_{T\wedge n}]$ whenever $T$ is a $\Bbb{N}_{0}\cup\{\infty\}$-valued random variable (and $(A_n)$ is as in the proof). So the real question is whether you can extract information about $A_{\infty}$ from $\Bbb{E}[A_T]$, and this is what the proof is trying to explain.

Comment: @SangchulLee oh right sorry MCT applies to both. But for case 2 in my attempt how to proceed? The proof in book and what Alex R. Says makes use of the stopped process and not $E[A_T]$

Comment: The proof essentially boils down to the observation that both $\Bbb{E}[A_T] < \infty$ and $\Bbb{P}(T = \infty) > 0$ are true. For these two to hold simultaneously, we must have that $A_{\infty} < \infty$.

Comment: @SangchulLee oh and for stopped process to have finite expectation we need $A_T$ to have finite expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've shown that there is a $c$ such that $P(T=\infty)>0$. So:

$$E[A_{T\wedge n}]=E[A_{T\wedge n}|T<\infty]P(T<\infty)+E[A_{T\wedge n}|T=\infty] P(T=\infty)$$

$$\to E[A_{T\wedge n}]=E[A_{T\wedge n}|T<\infty]P(T<\infty)+\frac{E[A_{T\wedge n}1_{T=\infty}]}{P(T=\infty)} P(T=\infty)$$

$$\to E[A_{T\wedge n}]=E[A_{T\wedge n}|T<\infty]P(T<\infty)+\frac{E[A_{n}1_{T=\infty}]}{P(T=\infty)} P(T=\infty)$$

$$\to E[A_{T\wedge n}]=E[A_{T\wedge n}|T<\infty]P(T<\infty)+\frac{A_{n}E[1_{T=\infty}]}{P(T=\infty)} P(T=\infty)$$

$$\to E[A_{T\wedge n}]=E[A_{T\wedge n}|T<\infty]P(T<\infty)+A_n P(T=\infty)$$

Both terms terms on the r.h.s are non-negative and you've also shown that $E[A_{T\wedge n}]$ is bounded above and you can take $n\rightarrow\infty$, so at the very least $A_\infty<\infty$ since $P(T=\infty)>0$

Comment: If $T=\infty$, then $A_{T \wedge n} = A_n$ and not $A_{\infty}$ ?

Comment: @BCLC: You're right, I'm one step ahead of myself. Just take the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Alex R., okay I think I get it. I edited to bounded above instead of finite and expanded center part. How is it?

Comment: i'll assume it's okay